# Traking iBeacon / BLE from Windows 8

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'd like to track iBeacon from windows 8 / C# using BLE dongle. I'm looking for a getting started because there is many question on the subject but very few answers.

Some answers talk about Gatt protocole to track BLE. Others explains that low level HDI must be use but not available on Windows.

I'd like to do a dead simple log of iBeacons and their proximity in C#

Comment: I dont see why this is not possible. In Android it would be pretty easy. Just scan the advertising packet/scan response. No need to connect or anything.

Comment: All iBeacon vendor made things for Android and iOS. Thre is some project for RaspberryPi. Windows 8.1 implements BLE since few month.

Comment: Did you get any success?

Comment: No I use a Raspberry Pi / NodeJS and a library on top of Bluez. With windows you must use low level API because iBeacon si not registered and so not available by Gatt (if I understood)

Comment: I basically want to communicate iOS device with windows 7/8 PC and i thought of iBeacons but i am not getting any where . Can you give me a head start for it, if you can or any other way may be!!

Comment: iBeacon is a protocol and an object that trigger a BLE signal when the iOS device see it it perform an action. You can simulate a beacon with RPi but you can't do it with windows (I didn't find things)

Comment: I got Windows 7 acting as a beacon and detecting beacons by writing a very minimal BLE stack in C# using libusb driver instead of original Bluetooth dongle driver

Comment: Very interesting do you have made a github ? or article ? or tutorial ?